# vim with servername for a filetype

Tags: vimscript

How I can launch gvim with servername for filetype tex?

What I am looking for is something like:

```
au filetype tex vim --servername "SERVERNAME"
```

I understand that it directly not possible, as vimrc is not loaded.
But is there any other way?

Right now I'm using a shell alias to do this, but I'd like to get it working as a Vim plugin.

Comment: Have you deleted the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this isn't really possible; not without some hackery anyway.

1. `--servername` has to be given as a commandline parameter, it can't be set later (`v:servername` is read-only).
2. Vim has no facility to restart itself with different parameters (e.g. like `exec()` function family in C).

The best you can do it to start Gvim from within Gvim with:

```
:execute ':!gvim --servername xxx ' . join(argv())
```

This has the problem of having two Gvim processes though (and thus Gvim windows); you'll will have to `:q` twice and the second Gvim will complain about swap files if the files are open in the first Gvim.

You can somewhat work around with with something like:

```
fun! RestartVim()
    " Only run this if servername is empty or the default
    if v:servername == '' || v:servername =~ '^gvim'
        " Only run for gvim, since this version doesn't work well with Vim
        if !has("gui_running")
            return
        endif

        " Close all buffers; prevents swap warnings
        bufdo bdelete

        " Run the second gvim
        execute ':!gvim --servername xxx ' . join(argv()) . ' &'

        " Quit the first Vim instance
        quit
    endif
endfun

augroup tex_restart
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype tex call RestartVim()
augroup end
```

I didn't extensively test this, and will probably have a caveat or two.

This version also won't work very well with regular Vim inside a terminal. Running `vim` with `&` won't work well since it won't be attached to the terminal, and I can't really think of a solution to prevent two `vim` processes.